# Ranger don't show document preview

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, gnome-terminal

I've installed ranger on UBUNTU 16.04(linux kernel 4.4.0-57), but something unusual has happened, when i run the program on terminal without sudo privileges the program shows a third panel where you can see a priview of the document, but it won't show nothing because it have no authorization level. When i run it with sudo privileges, the program has the authorization level but it won't show me the preview panel.

I want ranger to show me the preview when i use sudo to run it.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, do not run a program with sudo privileges like that, I'm not saying ranger will do bad things to your machine, but it is very bad practice. Second, show us the output of your ranger scope.sh file. This is usually find in ~/.config/ranger

Comment: Thank you for the advice, in fact you're right, and i did as recommended.